# Texture problem: model only renders in black and white

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

So working with a head model, I have a color image for texturing the face/scalp/neck and have the UV mapped properly to the image but when I render the image is always in black and white only.  I cannot find anyplace in any settings or in materials or texture panes where I can see why this should be so.  If I delete all materials and try to make a new one, I am only allowed to select black and white images of the color texture.  If I reload or replace the texture with the same image again, same thing.  It is in color in the Texture selection in the 3d model window but as soon as I render it, in the 3d window or via actually rendering of the still image, it is black and white.

WTF?

Here's some screen captures:
[image: Material panel]

[image: Texture panel]

Comment: Did you set the color management look to greyscale?

Comment: Where would I find that? I could have accidently hit a hot key at some point and not realize it but where is that setting?  Looking at output in the "camera" pane, it is set to RGB and 16 bit color.  I don't know of any other settings.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.  In the material pane under preview one of the settings was wrong.  I changed "color" to  image texture and then was allowed to select the texture image.  That corrected the color rendering issue.